# Xcode project won't build after running Clean My Mac removed development junk files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

This Xcode project won't build after running Clean My Mac. It looks like the program cleaned out some "development junk files" and now I'm getting errors like 'Foundation/Foundation.h' not found.

The project builds fine on my laptop but not on another Mac. (Basically no project builds on the Mac any more.) Also a brand new project also fails to build for with the same errors

[image]

Two things I've tried but still the problem persists:

1. a clean and build.
2. I've searched and found that one of the solutions might be to clear the Framework search path, as you can see though mine is empty:

[image: Framework Search Paths]

thanks for any help

Comment: Just restore the missing files from your most recent backup.

Comment: import foundation framework and add import<foundation/foundation.h> in your header file.

Comment: the project was fine before and I had the import directive for <foundation/foundation.h> in the header. you mean to remove the framework and then add it again in the Link Binaries With Libraries?

Comment: do I need to re-install XCode? The project builds fine on my laptop but not on another Mac. Basically no project builds on the Mac any more.

Comment: Have you checked under 'Link Binary With Libraries' under Build Phases to ensure that Foundation.framework is listed?

Comment: yes. I even removed then re-added. I've chosen to un-install and re-install Xcode. Even a new project won't build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by uninstalling Xcode with Clean My Mac and then re-installing Xcode through the AppStore.

Answer (score 3):

As a developer of CleanMyMac I'd like to thank you for reporting this issue :) We've fixed this in CleanMyMac version 1.10.5.